# Obtener objeto usando SELECT JSON_EXTRACT de MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json

tengo el siguiente json guardado en una tabla:

> [{"lesson_id": 1, "name": "Lesson 1"}, {"lesson_id": 2, "name": "Lesson 2"}, {"lesson_id": 3, "name": "Lesson 3"}]

Lo que necesito es ver si en este JSON esta un objeto determinado por ejemplo: "lesson_id" : 2,
Si esta en este json que me regrese solo ese objeto

> {"lesson_id": 2, "name": "Lesson 2"}

Tengo algo así, pero no logro encontrar la forma de que me regrese solo ese objeto

La consulta que estoy usando esta así.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(lessons_viewed, '$[**saber esto mediante el lesson_id**]') 
AS object 
FROM clients WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(lessons_viewed, 
'$[**saber esto mediante el lesson_id**].lesson_id') = 2
```

Pero necesito ver la forma que me mande el objeto de forma dinámica, haciendo que busque en todos los objetos y me regrese solo ese objeto del JSON

Gracias por su atención

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar:

```
SELECT 
    test.id,
    JSON_EXTRACT(prueba.json_list, CONCAT('$.list[', ind.ind, ']')),
    ind.ind
FROM
    prueba
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 0 AS ind UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ind UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ind) ind
WHERE
    JSON_LENGTH(json_list, "$.list") > ind.ind
    AND JSON_EXTRACT(json_list, CONCAT('$.list[', ind.ind, '].type')) = "color";
```

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas con el código cambiando las variables en cuanto sepa algo te aviso, muchas gracias Hernando